# How would this chart continue going down all the way to the end of the finger board and continue to relate into the staff?

Tags: violin, fingerboard

[image]How would this chart continue all the way down the finger board? I cannot figure out how to discern notes that would look identical from each other on the staff.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/jnn2.....n.jpg?dl=0

I saw this site and it seems to infer that each note scale changes in each position and you follow the corresponding staff arrangement that they have shown for each string and that shifts in position by which notes are read can be identified by dots or lines on top of each other. But, that is not true, that only exists in their sheet music from what I have found. I would like to be able to clearly make out every note on the fingerboard when I look at sheet music. But, with all that is out on the web, I cannot get past the first seven rows of notes that go up to DAEB.

https://www.violinonline.com/f.....vanced.htm

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Need help with fingering positions of violin](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/94923/need-help-with-fingering-positions-of-violin)

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to be able to clearly make out every note on the fingerboard when I look at sheet music.

Sheet music does not generally indicate which string a given note is played on.  Some notes will be unambiguous, but in other cases it may be ambiguous.  If you see an F on the top line of the treble staff, you could play it on the E string or the A string.  It depends on the context, on what other notes are around it.  If there are lots of higher notes in the passage, you'll have your left hand in a higher position, and you'll want to play the F on a lower string.  Learning how to develop a fingering plan for a passage of music on the page is part of learning to become a string player.  The explicit dots and lines used in this method are simply a way of showing you what to do before you've developed the skill yourself.

Answer (score 2):

As phoog has said, this issue is common to stringed instruments. I play the guitar and learning all the notes along the freboard requires hard work, memorization and lots of practice. I don't even know all the notes across all the strings: I have a fair knowledge of the 6th (and 1st) and 5th strings. The rest I just find out on the fly by doing some fretboard arythmetics.

The notes on each string are arrayed following a chromatic scale, with a 5th jump from each string on the violin.

The lowest (4th) string should be

G - G#/Ab - A - A#/Bb - B - C - C#/Db - D - D#/Eb - E - F - F#/G# - G and it repeats from here.

The same thing would happen with the other strings, only starting in a different point in the chromatic scale.

If there are no good drawings / diagrams on the internet I would suggest coming up with your own (and then sharing it!).

Comment: +1 for "make your own chart." I do one page charts for lots of things. Sometimes you need to work out things on your own to really develop an understanding.